# How secure is storing IOTA in Ledger Nano S?

Tags: security

Is storing IOTA in Ledger Nano S completely secure?
I am asking because IOTA doesn't use elliptic-curve cryptography.

Does storing and using IOTA in Ledger Nano S may make it easier for an attacker to find a private key of another cryptocurrency stored in ledger nano?

Answer (score 1):

if I may ask, what makes elliptic-curve cryptography more secure than IOTA's approach?

The seed is as safe as your other private keys and are affected by your threat model.

Please refer to the manufacturer for hardware specific concerns.
e.g.:

https://support.ledger.com/hc/en-us/articles/115005321449-Check-hardware-integrity

https://www.ledger.com/ledger-nano-x-bluetooth-security-model-of-a-wireless-hardware-wallet/

https://ledger-donjon.github.io/